# quickly manipulate and add duplicates of a word in Vim line by line

Tags: regex, vim

I have a really simple task but I can't find a way to do it; I have a text file that is composed like so

```
$CC
$CXX
```

where each line is the name of an environment variable and I would like to morph the previous into

```
echo "CC"$CC
echo "CXX"$CXX
```

and of course adding text in before and after each word on each line it's easy, especially in visual mode, but I can't really find a way to say to `vim` "copy the word after the dollar sign and paste it at some point in the sequence that I input in visual mode"

Someone got some ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this help?

```
:%s/\v\$(\S*)/echo "\1"&/
```

Comment: that's a cute baby ;)

Comment: @AmitJoki **vim rocks**  ;)

Comment: BTW @Kent, does VIM has a separate flavour of regex?

Comment: do you happen to have a link to a quick reference for this kind of syntax ? looks like there are similarity with `awk` syntax

Comment: I guess you mean [tag:sed].

Comment: @pfnuesel neither. sed (with -r gnu sed) and gnu awk support ERE, but vim supports much more than that. in vim help there is a section to compare PCRE and vim's regex.  one can read about it

Comment: @user2485710 see my above comment, not `awk/sed` like. if you want to understand the regex in the answer, `:h magic` `:h \S` `:h :s`

Comment: @Kent so there are no specific names for this syntax ?

Comment: Aspects of ed went on to influence ex, which in turn spawned vi. The regex flavor is that of ed which appeared in 1971. Where as Perl appeared in 1987. Now Vim has its own improvements to ex's regex like `\v`, `\zs`, look-behind's, and look-ahead's.

Comment: @user2485710 what do you mean a name? like : vim regex?

Comment: @Kent I guess, I was expecting `vim` to simply use something like a external utility or a component specifically designed for regex, PCRE is really a generic term, so I was trying to focus on a more specific term to help my digging .

Comment: @PeterRincker the problem with this kind of stuff is that after 40+ years it's easy to lose tracks of the features and good docs are hard to find; something become something else and it all appear to be mix of things from a different era, at least in my case.

Comment: @user2485710 vim has its own regex engine to process regex. `:h two-engines` and `:h regex`

Comment: @user2485710 The wonderful thing about vim is its documentation. I can not recommend enough the usefulness of reading the documentation. Read `:h pattern` and `:h perl-patterns` for regex. I believe documentation is a critical part sharpening the saw that Bram Moolenaar spoken of in [Seven habits of effective text editing](http://www.moolenaar.net/habits.html).

Comment: @PeterRincker the famous shortcuts for `vim`, there is 1 big problem with them, they really don't work that well on some keyboard layouts; I keep that in mind since I started using `vim` but I can't find myself using that feature that much .